# TensorFlow saver error: resources exhausted

Tags: tensorflow

Does anybody know what might cause an InternalError when I use saver.save(sess, save_path, global_step=step)? I get an error generating my (tmp) checkpoint file and the error says I have "resources exhausted: *temp filename*".

Thank you!

Comment: Is it possible that you've run out of space on your temp file system?

Comment: How much memory for processing do you have? use [free -m](https://www.linux.com/community/blogs/133-general-linux/745323-5-commands-to-check-memory-usage-on-linux) to find out. I have 8G as 2G Ram, 2G Swap Partition, 2 2G Swap files

Comment: Thank you both.

I was being an idiot. Ran out of disk space and I was checking the wrong drive to see if I had free space (network computer etc.).

Comment: This actually happened to me too using the aws ec2 with 8 gigs... :/

Comment: This is happening to me as well, and the machine I'm running on has over 200GB of free memory.